# Conditional DataGrid MultiBinding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

I've got a DataGrid in a WPF window whose itemsSource could be different based on a condition. if condition is true itemsSource is set to a list of objects of type classA otherwise is set to a list of objects of type classB.
In DatagridColumns I have some DataGridTextColumn that shoud be binded to members of classA or classB based on type of itemsSource.

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="MyDataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title">
             <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                  <MultiBinding>
                       <Binding Path= "MemberOfClassA"/>
                       <Binding Path= "MemberOfClassB"/>
                 </MultiBinding>
             </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
          </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In my C# code I have:

```
ClassA
{
    public string MemberOfClassA {get;set;}
    ...
}
ClassB
{
    public string MemberOfClassB {get;set;}
    ...
}

List<ClassA> listA = ...;
List<ClassB> listB = ...;

MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = condtion? listA : listB;
```

How could I implement a converter for the MultiBinding to select the binding path based on condition. Any alternative suggestion would be also appreciated.

Comment: add a style to your datagrid, add a datatrigger to the style, set the itemssource in that datatrigger

Comment: I would not try to shuffle bindings like this. Also, this is not what multibindings are for. I suggest following Andy's suggestion in his answer. Alternatively, write two DataGridTextColumns, one for MemberOfClassA and one for MemberOfClassB. Control their `Visibility` with a binding that uses a valueconverter. Another option is to have both ClassA and ClassB implement a common interface that has a single property, MemberOfAOrB. A's implementation of that property returns MemberOfClassA; B's returns MemberOfClassB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this converter useful:

```
 public class CellConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        foreach(object value in values)
        {
            if (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                continue;
            else
                return value;
        }
        return null;
    }       

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

}
```

and in XAML file:

```
<MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource CellConverter}">
     <Binding Path="MemberOfClassA"/>
     <Binding Path="MemberOfClassB"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

While the ItemsSource is set to just one of the types, for the other type the values would not be set. so the return value would be of type DependencyProperty.UnsetValue and the converter just returns the expected value.

**Edit**

as @EdPlunkett mentioned in comments, in this method the values could not be edited in DataGrid so it's useful just for readonly columns. For editable columns it's better to add multiple DataGridTextColumn for each type and bind their `Visibility` property to a value converter.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes you're right! for readonly columns this is good and for editable columns as you mentioned in previous comment there should be different columns with control on their 'Visibility'. In case of existing editable columns a combination of these two methods would work!

Answer (score 1):

If the columns of the datagrid are going to be different then changing column binding will be rather messy.

You could create two usercontrols with a datagrid in each. Givng you a datagrid suits each.

Switch out the content of a contentcontrol to the appropriate one.

Either by using a datatemplateselector or by putting your two collections in two different viewmodel types and using datatype to select the appropriate usercontrol as a datatemplate.